# subprocess.check_output get hung during execution

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, popen

I'm working on a script to automate the tcServer installation and configuration. I use the check_output function to start the tcServer instance after the installation, but it get hung. If I check the tcServer logs, the instance started successfully without problems. But the script stops there doing nothing.
Although, if I execute the same code with popen, it runs smoothly.
This is the code with check_output:

```
dirInst = '/opt/pivotal/pivotal-tc-server-standard/' + instanceName
subprocess.check_output(dirInst + '/bin/tcruntime-ctl.sh start', shell=True)
```

This is the code with popen:

```
arguments = dirInst + '/bin/tcruntime-ctl.sh start'
subprocess.Popen([arguments], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
time.sleep(10)
```

I know that shell=True is a vulnerability, but I just wanted to save time during the testing.
I need to use the sleep (10) to give some time to start the instance.
Any idea?

Thanks